# Angular Component Service Injection Does Not Work With Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

## Problem

I am having an issue where Angular's DI only seems to work if I use the `@Inject` decorator (i.e. `@Inject(TestService)`) in the constructor of the component when injecting a service. This seems to work fine (without using `@Inject`) whenever I use a standard Angular CLI test project, but when I create the same project without Angular CLI manually using webpack (as seen below), I always get:

> compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

## Code

**./src/app/main.js**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**./src/app/test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    write() {
        console.log('SOMETHING');
    }
}
```

**./src/app/app.module.js**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { TestService } from './test.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    providers: [TestService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**./src/app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    styles: [],
    template: 'Hello',
})
export class AppComponent {
    // Works if you uncomment the @Inject decorator below
    constructor(/*@Inject(TestService)*/ test: TestService) {
        test.write();
    }
}
```

**./src/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**./webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isVendorModule = (module) => {
    if (!module.context) {
        return false;
    }

    const nodeModule = module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
    return nodeModule;
};

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        quiet: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    },
    entry: {
        'app/main': './src/app/main.ts'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/*')
        ]),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'app/vendor',
            chunks: ['app/main'],
            minChunks: isVendorModule
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            chunks: ['app/vendor', 'app/main']
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    }
};
```

**./tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "ES2016",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {}
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

## Reproducible Sample

You can get the source for this question's sample project on [GitHub here](https://github.com/kspearrin/angular-webpack-problem). Then just run:

- `npm install`
- `npm run server`
- visit localhost:8080

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import `core-js` inside your `app.module.ts` which adds polyfills.

```
import 'core-js';
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.